# Enforcing minimum cardinality in One To many design?

Tags: mysql

If we have the following One to Many database design.

```
Team

+------+-----------+
| t_id | team_name | 
+------+-----------+
| 100  |  germany  |
+------+-----------+



FootballPlayers

+--------+------+-------------+--------+
|  p_id  | t_id | player_name | number |
+--------+------+-------------+--------+
|    1   |  100 |   T Muller  |   11   |
|    2   |  100 |   T Peters  |   8    |
|    1   |  100 |    Messi    |   2    |
|    1   |  100 |   J Cole    |   10   |
+--------+------+-------------+--------+
```

If a **Team** must have a minimum of 11 **FootballPlayers**, how can we enforce this within the database design?

Could I use Triggers? Perhaps One To Many is wrong? ...

Comment: You need to think more deeply about your business rule. Assume you write a trigger that prevents inserts or deletions if the number of players on the team will become < 11. Then how will you add the first player on to any team with an insert? In international competition the rule is actually much more complicated as 23 players may dress for a game and 30 may travel with the team. (I think I got the numbers correct from memory.)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The "first player" must be added to either a team existing of minimum 11 players, or with another 10 players at once within a transaction. I haven't used triggers before, but it sounds logically allowable. As for a team having 23/30 players, I do not need a maximum, just a minimum.

Comment: Triggers fire on every insert; not once per transaction.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens If that is the case, then is it even possible to create such a rule? It will not be possible to enter 1 single row into the FootballPlayers table as the trigger would fail as  their will never be 11 rows...

Comment: Exactly! That is my initial point that you have not actually come up with correct business rules, and that Declarative Referential Integrity (DRI) will be tricky in such an instance. To start with you will need a Player table that *does not* have a foreign key to Team; that will have to be a separate N-N lookup table from Team to Player, and you can enforce rules on it such as a Player can only be on one National team at a time.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens My business rules I would like to keep (11 players per team), but it is the implementation of my business rules which is the problem... As for 1 player being apart of one team at a time - I am not concerned about this. The only business rule I need help implementing here is how to enforce a fact that the FootballPlayers table has a minimum of 11 players per 1 team. I am trying to picture the separate N-N table now, Thanks.

Edit: By N-N, do you mean a table consisting of 11 columns? If not I am thinking this possibly can work.

Comment: **That is an invalid business rule**. There are lots of times when a team does not comprise eleven players: After a red-card; while team selection is occurring; after any of the three substitutions allowed during a match. I could go on. The reason you are having such difficulty enforcing the rule is that it is inherently an invalid rule. The rule should be something more like: "Is this a valid starting match roster for the team?", which will vary by match and will have exactly eleven spots, and so can be a additional table with its own constraints.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Peter as I said in the above comment I am not concerned with other business rules. The only business rule I want to enforce is a minimum of 11 players per team. I do not need factors such as red cards, international players etc... Please do not digress with this - it is also a reason why I made my opening post so small just go highlight one point. I appreciate you are trying to help me avoid future problems but you are introducing these rules which do not exist in my domain, my domain is not as complex as red card, int'l/duplicate players etc(legitimately they may be in RL)

Comment: 1) [A good answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261082) (I really like the idea of using a view), and 2) although not germane to the help you're seeking, the minimum permissible number of players on a football team is 7 (for international and professional play under FIFA affiliates), although most teams field 11 players most of the time.

Answer (score -2):

Declare a constraint on Players, something like

check (10 < (select count(*) from p_id where t_id = @t_id))

and ensure that your application inserts at least 11 players the first time.

It's not clear this is a good idea, though.  It's one thing to say *every player belongs to a team*.  It's something else to say *all teams have 11 players*.  In the first case, you're enforcing referential integrity: what would teamless player be?  (Well, you might have worked with him.  I have.)  In the second case, you're imposing a business rule: does a team *cease to exist* if player #11 quits?  Is it the case that when player #11 quits, the whole team must be deleted?

There might be such a rule, but it seems more likely (from this distance) that the team continues to exist but becomes ineligible to play.  In that case you might want a view

```
create view EligibleTeams as 
select * from Teams as t where 10 < 
    (select count (t_id) from Players where t_id = t.t_id)
```

Also, is it clear you need `t_id` and `p_id`?  Not to me.  I think your keys are the names of the players and the teams.  Definitely you don't want two **Ravens** or whatever, and the odds that you'll have two players named *Roger Staubach* on one team are longer than the Cowboys winning the World Series.

Comment: There were two Don Davies in my Grade 12 class, of less than 20 students total. There were two James Bresnahan in one of my University classes, of only about 50 students. Using the Name of a person as a Primary key is a really bad idea.

Comment: @JamesKLowden How can I declare a constraint? Is that the same as a trigger?
As for players not in a team or players quitting etc - I am not concerned with these rules, they do not exist in my domain so we don't have to worry about them.

The **only** rule is a team must have a minimum of 11 players.